# adjoint to the inclusion of abelian divisible groups

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, abelian-groups, adjoint-functors

I am studying for a group theory exam which doubles as an introduction to category theory. In the chapter on abelian groups, we introduced the notion of a divisible group.

I consider the category $Ab_{div}$ of divisible abelian groups, this is a full subcategory of $Ab$, and as such there is a natural inclusion into $Ab$. Often times, we get interesting constructions/operations when considering adjoints of inclusions. For example if we consider $Ab_{tor}$ the category of abelian groups where every element is torsion, than the adjoint to the inclusion functor is the functor which sends $A$ to $T(A)$ its torsion subgroup.

Does the inclusion of $Ab_{div}$ into $Ab$ have an adjoint?

Comment: You haven't specified left/right adjoint. Let's assume right. Then I think you can take $A \mapsto D(A)$, where $D(A)$ is the maximal divisible subgroup of $A$ (the sum of all divisible subgroups).

Comment: I am happy with left or right adjoint, so thanks